# Transform an xml table by sql xquery

Tags: xquery

I would like to transform an XML table to a JSON array or an array of arrays.

[image: Pic of code]

Comment: plz insert your code better than adding a pic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use an XQuery 3.1 processor like Saxon 9.8 or later or BaseX 9?

```
array { */* ! array { * ! string() } }
```

should suffice for the second option of an array of arrays. For the array of maps you can use

```
array { */* ! map:merge(* ! map { local-name() : string() }) }
```

Examples at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8u/0 and https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8u/1.